# addpath and connection between matlab and C#?

Tags: c#, matlab

I have created matlab file (function) which contains save statement I have to save image histogram value(Hist)

```
folder_name = 'query'; 
addpath(folder_name); 
file_name = [folder_name '\image(1)'];
 save(file_name,'Hist');
```

this runs perfectly using matlab with no problem the problem occurs when I run the code using C# after converting the matlab file to .dll file it cannot addpath to folder_name or find it although I have added the folder to the package of deployment tool

Comment: Could you explain your code? What is `folder_name`, is this a function? Why do you edit the search path in your code instead of setting it up once?

Comment: It might be of your interest: http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/11/path-management-in-deployed-applications/

Comment: folder_name  isnot a function it is a name of the folder which i wanna save the result on it 
my code calculate image histogram  then save this historam as .mat file into the folder_name which i call  it query

Comment: Do you have the C# code?